# override method FinishedLaunching causing a black screen on the ios device

Tags: maui

I'm assuming I'm missing something in the override method in the AppDelegate for iOS on .net Maui.

I'm attempting to add some code in which needs to be added at the AppDelegate.  It doesn't exactly say to add it in the FinishedLaunching method, but that is one that I found doing research on this issue.  I at first thought it was my add in code, but I took that out and re-ran the application.  The application starts on the iPad, but goes black with the battery charge in the upper right.  It's responsive to closing when I stop the debugging in VS.

When I comment out the FinishedLaunching code, it works like it used to.

This is the code:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    return true;
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the "return true" line and it does get hit.  I also set a breakpoint in the MauiProgram.cs on the "return builder.Build()" and it hits that prior to the FinishedLaunching() override method.

I assume since I am overriding this method that there is some code that needs to be added in to replace what was there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to pass the information back to the parent. It should look like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // do your stuff here...

    return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
}
```

Comment: In another 12 hours I can, but thank you for the reminder.